# Configuring Quartz for database servers

Tags: mysql, sql-server, postgresql, quartz-scheduler

I am using Quartz scheduler version 1.5.2, the schedules are stored on a MSSQL database. Quartz is running in a cluster mode with the property -

```
org.quartz.jobStore.selectWithLockSQL = select lock_name from qrtz_locks with (updlock,rowlock) where lock_name=?
```

Works fine.. so far!! 
If I need to make functionality available across different database - Postgres, MySQL,Oracle; the above property needs to change.

How would I rewrite the query to run across all databases? Or is there any other way to achieve easy portability?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [`org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass`](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/configuration/ConfigJobStoreTX) property:

> Driver delegates understand the particular 'dialects' of varies database systems. [...]

Quartz supports out-of-the box the following database (dialects):

- MSSQL
- PostgreSQL
- WebLogic
- Oracle
- Cloudscape
- DB2 (v6, v7, v8)
- HSQLDB
- Pointbase
- Sybase

I know also successfully used it with H2 and MySQL.

Comment: Thank you Tomasz. So if I understand, I need to configure the "delegate" property based on the type of database and not modify the query. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @WinMan: exactly. If standard (default) is not working for you, just configure different delegate. I don't think there is any way to change the query directly (well, you can always write your own delegate).

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz:that means when we change the database,we still have to change the property either the lock one or the delegate one ?

Comment: @Rips: yes. However it's not a big deal, isn't it? In most JPA providers you have to set database dialect first.

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz:I am working on a product which should be able to work with mssql,oracle etc.Though we are using JPA,we dont set any database dialect as you have mentioned.In the jboss-oracle-ds,we have confifured the data source and binded to JNDIname and same is looked upto into the datasource property in the persistence.xml.Now even I was facing the same problem.Original code for the  product needed to be changed to satisfy different db's for this quartz issue.What we have done as workaround is to put this 'sql' in the properties file outside the WAR so that original code remains same.